# Update android (homescreen) widget from php file

Tags: php, android, widget

I want to make a android widget that it will update from a php file. i found a lot of examples about widgets and a lot of examples of how to retrieve data from php to an activity but i didn't manage to do it.
i need something like this example (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html) but instead of a random number i need to take the number from my php file..

php file it output a single number that i need to include in my widget (http://www.angryboards.com/data/larnaca/test.php)

this the WidgetProvider class, but when i am trying to call the AsyncTask in onUpdate() it crashes.

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

 private TextView textView;


  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

      //call AsyncTask
       String serverURL = "http://www.angryboards.com/data/larnaca/test.php";
         new async().execute(serverURL);
         String txt = textView.getText().toString();


    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {






      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget_layout);

      // Set the text
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, txt);

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
  }

 private class async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();


          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);




    }
  }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tasos.widgettest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"

     />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tasos.widgettest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <receiver
   android:icon="@drawable/logo"
   android:label="Example Widget"
   android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
   <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
   </intent-filter>

   <meta-data
      android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
      android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver> 

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:minWidth="300dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="3000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

and in layout i have a textview (android:id="@+id/update")
Thanks

Comment: There are so many examples on this site downloading the echo of a php file. So what is your special problem?

Comment: I have managed to download the data in activity class with (HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.angryboards.com/data/larnaca/test.php")... and its working fine, but in the widget its different and i don't know how to approach this..  Thanks

Comment: Remove the php code as it is irrelevant. Post your download code please. In the widget it will be almost the same.

Comment: In a widgetprovider you can use `remoteViews.setTextViewText()` as is done in the Vogella example you use. So that would be easy and you were done. But you call postData() in onCreate() so you are doing that on the main thread. This is only possibele is you use an old Android version. Start wit putting that code in an AsyncTask and set the textview in onPostExecute. Having done that its only a few steps to adapt it for a widget.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly but i will read more about AyncTask and i will try to do it. Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: Look at Vogella's `DownloadWebPageTask`in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: i was trying to do it with the async task as you told me but when i was calling the async task from onUpdate() it crashes.

Comment: It crashes before the task is ready. It crashes already at `String txt = textView.getText().toString();` because textView == null. You can see that in the LogCat and the stacktrace in Eclipse. Learn to use them. If it would not have crashed on mentioned statement it would crash in OnPostExecute at statement ` textView.setText(result);` as still texttView== null. Remove that private variable completely and use -as said before- `remoteViews.setTextViewText()`.

Answer (score 0):

Done! i did a service that contains an AsyncTask and i call the service from appwigdetprovider.

My UpdateWidgetService.java

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

public String string;
public String inputLine;
public StringBuilder txt;
public BufferedReader in;
public URL url;



@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {


AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

RemoteViews remoteViews = new     RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MyWidgetProvider.class);
clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,allWidgetIds);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext() , 0,     clickIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


//refresh tapping the screen
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
new DownloadTask().execute();


appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
}
stopSelf();

super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

try {
url = new URL("http://www.angryboards.com/data/larnaca/latest_wind_value.php");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
inputLine = null;
txt = new StringBuilder();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
string = in.readLine();
txt.append(inputLine);
txt.append('\n');


}
in.close();


} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication());
//get widget ids for widgets created
ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(getApplication(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widget);
//update text
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, txt);
//refresh widget to show text
widgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetIds, remoteViews); 


}
}


}
```

MyWidgetProvider.java

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

  private static final String LOG = "com.tasos.widgettest";


  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
  int[] appWidgetIds) {

Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
// Get all ids
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
    MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

// Build the intent to call the service
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
    UpdateWidgetService.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

// Update the widgets via the service
context.startService(intent);




  }

}
```